# Как пройти авторизации службы (отправить параметры пользователя в header)?

Tags: c#, wcf

У меня есть WCF служба и у неё авторизация. Чтобы пройти её авторизации и использовать методы службы нужен отправить параметры пользователя в header. Можете подсказать как это сделать?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14621858/312041

Comment: Я разобралась с заголовком и авторизацией. Теперь как мне эту авторизацию связать с выполнением команды из службы

Comment: Молодец! Про второй вопрос - я понятия не имею. Наверное его лучше отдельным вопросом задать